# How to get a list of submatrices given a huge matrix and two vector of vector as indices in Julia

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I have a matrix W (of some size), and two Vector{Vector} xList, and yList. I know I can access a submatrix of W using each element of xList and yList (which are Vectors themselves). I want to know a way I can vectorize this over all elements of these two Vectors.

Eg. let W matrix be

```
W=rand(1:10, 3, 3)
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 6   2   5
 1   5  10
 7  10   6
```

and

```
xList=[[1, 2], [1, 3]]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]
 [1, 3]

yList=[[2, 2], [3, 1]]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [2, 2]
 [3, 1]
```

I basically want to vectorize the following for loop :

```
 Wsub=[]
 for i in 1:size(xList)[1]
      push!(Wsub, W[xList[i], yList[i]])
 end

julia> Wsub
2-element Vector{Any}:
 [2 2; 5 5]
 [5 6; 6 7]
```

The actual matrix I have is roughly 1000 x 500, and the xList and yList will have around 25000 Vectors each. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the loop, you have `getindex.((W,), xList, yList)` to get the same result. This can also be written as `getindex.(Ref(W), xList, yList)` if you prefer. Broadcasting is used here to apply the `getindex` function elementwise to the pairs of indices in `xList` and `yList`, using `W` as the matrix being indexed.

```
julia> xList = [[1, 2], [1, 3]]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 2]
 [1, 3]

julia> yList = [[2, 2], [3, 1]]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [2, 2]
 [3, 1]

julia> W = rand(1:10, 3, 3)
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 6  2  1
 5  8  7
 6  1  5

julia> getindex.((W,), xList, yList)
2-element Vector{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [2 2; 8 8]
 [1 6; 5 6]
```